# regarding models choices in django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models

Is there any way if a choice is removed from the model choices it should automatically delete  entry in the db too.

like

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    year_in_school = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                      choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
                                      default=FRESHMAN)
```

now i have removed (JUNIOR, 'Junior') choice from the list. In Student table it should delete the records with Junior.

i am using appengine for the release. is there any chance to check while deploying the appengine application and send the change to db ?

Any help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

No. Do a south [data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations).

Comment: but it requires some manual effort. i want to it be automatic. it should work like a signal.On change it automatically update the db.

Comment: yes, i am using appengine for the release. is there any chance pre check while deploying the appengine application.

Comment: Then you probably want to make it `ForeignKey`. It's more joins, but you can edit `YEAR_IN_SCHOOL` in db and get related fields cleaned. The behavior you describe is cascade FK delete. But personally I would stay with hard-coded values and data migrations as they don't seem to change often.

Comment: i have a lengthy list of choices in my application as per restriction i can't put directly in the db,the choice list be a file and this choices keep changes multiple times thats the reason looking for some automated solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the last comment. Are those choices in db already? Db is perfect for often changing things. :) That what it's for. :)

Comment: If the list changes frequently you shouldn't restart the app every time. What is the restriction preventing you from keeping it in the db? Just watch the file and update db accordingly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33758/discussion-between-sush-and-krzysztof-szularz)

Answer (score 0):

So, I think this question requires a clarification.

If you want a model which has a **variable** set of choices, it is against the model idea. Model in Django means something that is only to be changed by hard coding it on the code, and not changing by users or during runtime of the server.

In this case you would want a new model (e.g. `StudentType`) and a ForeignKey on your `Student`. This way, consistency can be applied by [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) and [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete) signals.

Krzysztof Szularz answer is assuming other thing out of your question (which might be the correct assumption), which is a normal situation in Django: you already have a model, but **a new version of your code** changed the set of choices.

In that case, as Krzysztof pointed out, Django does not have the feature to automatically update the database according to models change. In that situation you have two choices:

1. either you use a third-party app for that ([south](http://south.aeracode.org/) being the most
   popular one)
2. you delete the entries by hand.

In either situations, they are meant to be used as a **change on the code**.